# Down arrow after the div is not centered

Tags: css, html

I've just made this `div`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/K5qdc/)

But the arrow after the `div` is not *center aligned*, once I insert the new `div` inside

**HTML**

```
<div id="hero_intro">
    <div class="quote">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#hero_intro {
    background: #f18c22;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    z-index: 5000;
    font-size: 32px;
}
#hero_intro:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: 150px;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #f18c22;
}
#hero_intro .quote {
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Please post the HTML/CSS here.

Comment: it's included on JSFIDDLE link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it `left: 50%;` which will make it center but not center exactly, so use `margin-left: -20px;` i.e 1/2 of total `width` of the `absolute` positioned triangle.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/K5qdc/4/)

```
#hero_intro:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  margin-top: 150px;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #f18c22;
  left: 50%; /*Add these*/
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

> Note: Make sure you use `position: relative;` for the parent container and then `position` the element accordingly.. Also use `bottom` attribute instead of `margin-top`

Better Solution, regardless of `height` of your element, getting rid of `margin-top` and assigning `position: relative;` to the parent container.

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/K5qdc/5/)

```
#hero_intro {
    background: #f18c22;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    z-index: 5000;
    font-size: 32px;
    position: relative;
}
#hero_intro:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    bottom: -20px;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #f18c22;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
#hero_intro .quote {
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `left: 50%;` to `#hero_intro:after` css. The parent container has to be `position: relative` obviously.

Answer (score 0):

here is the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/K5qdc/3/

```
#hero_intro{
background: #f18c22 ;
height: 150px;
text-align: center;
color:#fff;
z-index: 5000;
font-size: 32px; }

#hero_intro:after { 
content: '';  
position: absolute;
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-left: 20px solid transparent;
border-right: 20px solid transparent;
border-top: 20px solid #f18c22;
bottom: 28px;
left:0;
margin: 0 auto;
right:0; }
```

the rest you can find it in fiddler